# How to change PodCIDR/PodCIDRs in my node

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I have setup a kubernete cluster with kubeadm in 2 beta metal. the cluster works well.
the kubeadm command I used:
    `sudo kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16`

When I do the the performance test,  I need to run more pods in the work node.  I met a mistake,
the PodCIDR in my work node is,`PodCIDR: 10.244.1.0/24`, so i can run 254 pods at most, although i have change the max-pod to 500.

So my question is how can i change the PodCIDR in my node. 
I have trid  to change to `/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-controller-manager.yaml` set
 `- --node-cidr-mask-size=16`,  and restart the kubelet,  but it makes no effort.

Comment: Hi @tony, what CNI plugin You use? If it is flannel I think [there](https://serverfault.com/questions/976513/is-it-possible-to-change-cidr-network-flannel-and-kubernetes) is answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

PodCIDR is managed by the CNI, depends on what CNI you're using. You might want to change the CNI config and restart every node.

Here is the reference: https://capstonec.com/help-i-need-to-change-the-pod-cidr-in-my-kubernetes-cluster/